# Is it possible to know the Gotra from the surname alone?

Tags: gotra

My surname is Mukhopadhyay. I belong to Bhardwaj Gotra. My maternal side's surname is Bandopadhyay and they belong to Kashyapa Gotra. Is it true that all persons with the surname Mukhopadhyay belong to Bhardwaj Gotra?

In general, is it possible to know the Gotra from the surname alone? What are the relationships between different Hindu surnames and Gotras?

Comment: I think, one cannot know. I have personally seen a lot of variations in any sort of correlation between the varna-caste & surnames and the gotras, if at all any. Also, the present day system of Surnames might be a modern concept.

Comment: The varna can be slightly guessed, but gotra it's next to impossible. Surnames got in use against the name of a individual to signify the rank given by the king. Although the kingdoms have dissolved, the surnames brought in use still flow. I have only seen chitpavan Brahmins to preserve their surnames from which their gotra can be guessed upto a certain extent (Few surnames have two or more gotras).

Comment: No that seems impossible, consider the case of Pathak that can be of any surname, of dwivedi, Trivedi,chaturvedi